# Function pointer pointing to built in function in C

Tags: c, function-pointers

I'm trying to set a function pointer to point to the `pow` function.
Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void){
    double (*func)(double, double) = pow;
  return 0;
}
```

But the program doesn't compile.
I get this error:

```
$ gcc test.c -o test

/tmp/ccD6Pmmn.o: In function `main':
test.c:(.text+0x8): undefined reference to `pow'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm using Ubuntu 15.10.

Anyone knows what's wrong with my code?

Thanks

Comment: Tried add `-lm` to the compile command?

Comment: Wow, that worked! Can you explain?

Comment: Some functions are in libraries that aren't linked with by default. Math functions like `pow()` are in the libm library, which you include by giving the `-lm` option.

Comment: Read you platform's documentation. Mine says, under pow, "Link with -lm."

Comment: That's true. Mine says the same. I didn't think of that. Thanks guys! =D

Comment: It's a historical quirk of old versions of gcc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to compile with -lm via command line or configure your IDE to add it into the linking process. This is due to the fact that some libraries are pretty large and to avoid taking up space in your program and compilation time, this was setup at the beginning of C when computers were much slower and would take MUCH more to compile and a matter of space was CRUCIAL.